# NullpointerException when reading properties Weblogic Server

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jax-rs, weblogic

I have this problem in Weblogic 12.2.1:
Extract from the log where the problem has been detected [log from the server]

```
####<06/12/2019 06:01:31 PM COT> <Info> <Deployer> <LIM-4WZN2X2> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <ffc7c770-2d51-4047-b19f-51eb060c58fa-0000000a> <1575673291126> <[severity-value: 64] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-149060> <Module demo-resource-1.0.0.war of application demo-resource-1.0.0 successfully transitioned from STATE_PREPARED to STATE_ADMIN on server AdminServer.> 
####<06/12/2019 06:01:31 PM COT> <Error> <HTTP> <LIM-4WZN2X2> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <ffc7c770-2d51-4047-b19f-51eb060c58fa-0000000a> <1575673291485> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "pe.demo.app.resource.conf.ApplicationConfig" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "demo-resource-1.0.0.war".
pe.demo.app.resource.exception.GeneralRuntimeException: Cannot read .properties file 
    at pe.demo.app.resource.conf.ApplicationConfig.readProperties(ApplicationConfig.java:78)
    at pe.demo.app.resource.conf.ApplicationConfig.getProperties(ApplicationConfig.java:45)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig.mergeApplications(ResourceConfig.java:1140)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig._setApplication(ResourceConfig.java:1077)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.setApplication(ResourceConfig.java:1029)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:342)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
```

The code where I call properties file is Java code using JAXRS:

```
package pe.demo.app.resource.conf;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import pe.demo.app.common.exception.ProviderExceptionMapper;
import pe.demo.app.common.property.Constantes;
import pe.demo.app.common.resource.exception.GeneralRuntimeException;
import pe.demo.app.resource.DemoResource;

@Singleton
@ApplicationPath( "api" )
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application{

  private static final String NAME_DIRECTORY       = "my-directory";
  private static final String NAME_VARIABLE        = "variable-weblogic-properties-root";
  private static final String NAME_FILE            = ".properties";

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses(){
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<Class<?>>();
    resources.add( DemoResource.class );
    resources.add( ProviderExceptionMapper.class );
    resources.add( com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class );
    resources.add( com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider.class );
    resources.add( com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON.class );
    resources.add( com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider.class );
    return resources;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> getProperties(){
    String nombrePropertieExterno = NAME_FILE;
    Map<String, Object> dataProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    dataProperties.putAll( readProperties( nombrePropertieExterno, false ) );
    return dataProperties;
  }

 private Map<String, Object> readProperties( String fileInClasspath, Boolean interno ){
    System.out.println( "method:[readProperties], nombre de properties recibido:-->" + fileInClasspath );
    InputStream is = null;
    String urlServer = "";
    try{
      if( interno ){
        is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( fileInClasspath );
      }
      else{

        String filePropertiesRoot = System.getProperty( NAME_VARIABLE );
        urlServer = filePropertiesRoot + NAME_DIRECTORY + File.separator + fileInClasspath;
        is = new FileInputStream( urlServer );
      }
      Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.load( is );
      map.putAll(
          properties.entrySet().stream().collect( Collectors.toMap( e -> e.getKey().toString(), e -> e.getValue() ) ) );
      is.close();
      return map;
    }
    catch( Exception e ){
      throw new GeneralRuntimeException( " Cannot read file " + fileInClasspath, e );
    }
  }
}
```

When war application deployed in Weblogic server, the error show in the log happend. But when I deploy in my own machine Weblogic 12.2.1 server, just work fine.

The line from error log where detect problem is:

```
Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: nullmy-directory/.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
```

This say variable for extract root directory for all my properties is null and cannot make all the path for my file .properties.

--> Another apps use the same method for extract this variable for weblogic environment and this error doesn't happend

For triying to recreate the error en my machine, I just did this:
(in the line where create FileInputStream :

```
// is = new FileInputStream( urlServer );
    //change for :
   is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( urlServer );
```

and now I have the error in my local Weblogic server is like the null, but is different because en dev environmet null is for weblogic variable and for this change null is for all path :( .

The application works fine, but error happend when sometimes restart the server o when redeploy my war app. but when use application, return the values from properties.

I think is lifecycle for REST apps when use JAXRS, but I'm new in JavaEE.

Thanks for your help and sorry for my english

Comment: This seems a bit silly to ask but is your properties file located at `my-directory/.properties`?

Comment: @randypaq13 yeah, becaue the app works fine how I say, return the values from .properties file

Comment: If the file is there than this is impossible for me to debug from here. Maybe try to invalidate cache and restart your IDE? The error says the file isn't there so clearly the program is not seeing the file in the correct directory. Sorry I couldn't give a more complete answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after creating a project with a similar configuration so as not to alter the tests that were being performed on the other component, the solution was: remove the component from the weblogic console, re-deploy the entire component (war application).